# Changing background colour of tr element on mouseover

Tags: html, css

I want to have my table rows highlighted on mouse over, but I have yet to find a way to do it that isn't using Javascript. Is this not possible in CSS?

I've tried this:

```
tr:hover {
    background: #000;
}
```

But that doesn't work. Using `td:hover` works, but I want to change the background colour of the whole table row.

Is there a pure CSS/HTML way to do it, or am I going to have to resort to Javascript?

Comment: I know its an old question, but you should consider accepting an answer.

Answer (score 123):

`<tr>`s themselves are very hard to access with CSS, try `tr:hover td {background:#000}`

Comment: When troubleshooting IE, it's crucial to know which version. Older versions of IE only support `:hover` on anchor elements (I believe it will work in IE7 only if you have a proper doctype). If you're dealing with older IE versions, try this: http://peterned.home.xs4all.nl/csshover.html Otherwise it's probably something you're doing wrong.

Comment: It is working only for alternate rows for me..any suggestions ?

Answer (score 29):

You could try:

```
tr:hover {
    background-color: #000;
}

tr:hover td {
    background-color: transparent; /* or #000 */
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/5VJ8n/).

Answer (score 14):

I had the same problem:

```
tr:hover { background: #000 !important; }
```

allone did not work, but adding

```
tr:hover td { background: transparent; }
```

to the next line of my css did the job for me!! 
My problem was that some of the TDs already had a background-color assigned and I did not know that I have to set that to TRANSPARENT to make the tr:hover work.

Actually, I used it with a classnames:

```
.trclass:hover { background: #000 !important; }
.trclass:hover td { background: transparent; }
```

Thanks for these answers, they made my day!! :)

Answer (score 9):

This will work:

```css
tr:hover {
    background: #000 !important;
}
```

If you want to only apply bg-color on TD then:

```css
tr:hover td {
    background: #c7d4dd !important;
}
```

It will even overwrite your given color and apply this forcefully.

Comment: Don't use `!important` in this context

Answer (score 4):

```
tr:hover td {background-color:#000;}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
tr:hover td.someclass {
   background: #EDB01C;
   color:#FFF;
}
```

only someclass cell highlight

Answer (score 2):

You can give the tr an id and do it.

```
tr#element{
    background-color: green;
    cursor: pointer;
    height: 30px;

}

tr#element:hover{
    background-color: blue;
    cursor: pointer;

}

<table width="400px">
<tr id="element">
<td></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

its easy . Just add !important at the end of your css line :

```
tr:hover {    background: #000 !important; }
```

Answer (score -1):

Try it

```
<!- HTML -->
<tr onmouseover="mOvr(this,'#ffa');" onmouseout="mOut(this,'#FFF');">

<script>
function mOvr(src,clrOver) { 
  if (!src.contains(event.fromElement)) { 
  src.bgColor = clrOver; 
  } 
} 
function mOut(src,clrIn) { 
  if (!src.contains(event.toElement)) { 
  src.bgColor = clrIn; 
  } 
} 
</script>
```

Comment: both functions are the same. You may as well just have one function.

Comment: Not quite. `fromElement` vs `toElement`. To be honest, not sure why I've scrolled this far down the page.