# Highlighting a table row on mouse hover

Tags: javascript, css

I'm creating a table in a javascript call and displaying the data via an iframe on the page the link is selected.  I'm trying to highlight a table row as the user hovers over a row.  I added a class to the table and then subsequent css code but I'm getting a parse error on the line where the table appears.  Any ideas on how to clear it?

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang = "en">
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystylesheet.css">
    <title>Tech Order Department.html</title>
    <meta charset = "UTF-8" />


</head>

<body>


    <h2>Completed Projects</h2>
<br>

<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "xxx";
$password = "xxx";
$dbname = "xxx";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
     die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

//Set up and run my Query

$sql = "SELECT Project, Client, DateReceived, LastName, FinalReviewDate, DateDelivered, DateAccepted FROM Projects
              WHERE DateAccepted IS NOT NULL
              ORDER BY DateAccepted DESC";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

//Display results

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
     echo "<table class="hoverTable"><tr><th>Client</th><th>Project</th><th>Point of Contact</th><th>Date Project Received</th><th>Final Review Date</th><th>Date Delivered</th><th>Date Accepted</th></tr>";
     // output data of each row
     while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
         echo "<tr><td>" . $row["Client"]. "</td><td>" . $row["Project"]. "</td><td> " . $row["LastName"]. "</td><td> " . $row["DateReceived"]. "</td><td> " . $row["FinalReviewDate"]. "</td><td> " . $row["DateDelivered"]. "</td><td> " . $row["DateAccepted"]. "</td></tr>";
     }
     echo "</table>";
} else {
     echo "0 results";
}

$conn->close();
?> 

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Maybe like this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5492951/636676

Comment: Can you include your `css` in your question? Thanks.

Comment: @Freddi I don't think any of those involve creating the table through javascript.  The CSS isn't the issue.  If it won't parse, the CSS won't matter.

Comment: @Tony please make sure than that you define the CSS in the context of the Iframe because this doesn't look like JS, more like PHP. Could you open the iframe for testing purposes in another window. Does it work there? Is the CSS there included?

Answer (score 2):

Unless there's something else amiss, the following style rule:

```
.hoverTable tr:hover {
background-color: rgba(255, 255, 0, 1);
}
```

should work perfectly.

**[ADDED]**

I understand the issue better now.

You need to escape the quotes in your HTML, so the parser doesn't mistake them for PHP quotes. Try this:

```
echo "<table class=\"hoverTable\">";
```

*Or* you can (simply) use single quotes in PHP and double quotes in HTML, like this:

```
echo '<table class="hoverTable">';
```

## =====

**Example of CSS & HTML together:**

```css
.hoverTable tr:hover {
background-color: rgba(255, 255, 0, 1);
}
```

```html
<table class="hoverTable">
  
<tr>
<th>Client</th>
<th>Project</th>
<th>Point of Contact</th>
<th>Date Project Received</th>
<th>Final Review Date</th>
<th>Date Delivered</th>
<th>Date Accepted</th>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>Client1</td>
<td>Project1</td>
<td>LastName1</td>
<td>DateReceived1</td>
<td>FinalReviewDate1</td>
<td>DateDelivered1</td>
<td>DateAccepted1</td>
</tr>
  
<tr>
<td>Client2</td>
<td>Project2</td>
<td>LastName2</td>
<td>DateReceived2</td>
<td>FinalReviewDate2</td>
<td>DateDelivered2</td>
<td>DateAccepted2</td>
</tr>
  
<tr>
<td>Client3</td>
<td>Project3</td>
<td>LastName3</td>
<td>DateReceived3</td>
<td>FinalReviewDate3</td>
<td>DateDelivered3</td>
<td>DateAccepted3</td>
</tr>
  
<tr>
<td>Client4</td>
<td>Project4</td>
<td>LastName4</td>
<td>DateReceived4</td>
<td>FinalReviewDate4</td>
<td>DateDelivered4</td>
<td>DateAccepted4</td>
</tr>
  
<tr>
<td>Client5</td>
<td>Project5</td>
<td>LastName5</td>
<td>DateReceived5</td>
<td>FinalReviewDate5</td>
<td>DateDelivered5</td>
<td>DateAccepted5</td>
</tr>
  
</table>
```

Comment: I have echo "<table class="hoverTable"> in the script, but I'm getting this Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING, expecting ',' or ';'  on the line where the table is given a class.  The code ran fine before I tried adding the hover for the table.  For some reason javascript doesn't like that line of code now.  My CSS wis the same as yours except for the color.

Comment: Ah. I see what the issue is. You need to escape the quotes in your HTML, so the parser doesn't mistake them for PHP quotes. Or you can (simply) use single quotes in PHP and double quotes in HTML, like this: `echo '<table class="hoverTable">';`

Comment: I forgot about php not liking multiple " ".  That cleared the parsing error and the table renders now, but the hover still won't work.  I thought it might be because I'm displaying the table results in an iframe, but I double checked on the page where the script is running and the table won't highlight there either.

Comment: @Tony - Please have a look at the snippet I have added to the post above and compare and contrast the `CSS` & `HTML` with the output from inside your `<iframe>` - that might be enough to help you identify why your CSS isn't working.